# Var in Javascript to be recovered in html code

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure if this is possible, but I am getting a variable after some text input from the user.  This variable is obtained in Javascript, but I need it later in the HTML body tag of my code.  Is there a way to do this?

This is the Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.alert("Documento ha sido adjuntado!")
 <!--
 var name = prompt("Referencia del Documento: ", "");
 //-->
 window.close();
 </script>
```

Comment: Yes, but I can't work out what it is that you want to do. Can you provide a step-by-step process that explains what you want? Do you want JavaScript to insert the variable somewhere in the `<body>` tag, or elsewhere into an element/node *within* the `body` element?

Comment: David, I need the string coming from the javascript to be inserted in mysql database using servlets. I need something that I can just declare a String="something" and that "something" is the value from Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could include a hidden element within your page and set the value you need within the hidden value, then when you need to reuse it, just reference the hidden field.

[**Working Example (Uses a textbox as opposed to a hidden field for viewing purposes)**](http://jsfiddle.net/FDRZS/)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="nameValue" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 window.alert("Documento ha sido adjuntado!")

 var name = prompt("Referencia del Documento: ", "");

 //Sets the hidden value with "name"
 document.getElementById('nameValue').value= name;

 window.close();
 </script>
```

**As per your specific question:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 window.alert("Documento ha sido adjuntado!")
 var name = prompt("Referencia del Documento: ", "");
 window.close();
 UpdateDatabase(name);

 function UpdateDatabase(yourString)
 {
     //Servlet call to Update Database with "yourString"
 }

 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Rionmonster, but I need to use the string straightaway, the option you are giving me is by using a form within HTML... let´s say I want to use the string to insert it into a table in mySQL database... how can I use this value? is there a way to just say: String=namevalue;

Comment: If you include the hidden value within the form, after you set the value in the prompt, it will be set within the form. So when you submit the form, it should have the value that you set with your prompt.

Comment: That is clear, I understand that, the issue is that I don´t want to use the form.  Basically I want the javascript prompt to allow the user to enter a document´s reference number, but on the same code I have a jsp tag that will insert the value into mysql. If I use the form I need to get another code to handle this.  Do you see what I am trying to do?

Comment: I believe I understand, so you have a separate function that you need to insert the value into the DB? If that is the case, you can access the "Document Reference Number" that is stored in the hidden field via: document.getElementById('nameValue'). So for your DB call, you could set the following: String = document.getElementById('nameValue'). I'll try to add an example

Answer (score 1):

Try using JavaScript to update the HTML element after you prompt for the value.

```
 var name = prompt();
 document.getElementById("MyElement").value = name;



<input type='text' id="MyElement" />
```

Comment: Thanks P. Campbell, but I need to use the string straightaway, the option you are giving me is by using a form within HTML... let´s say I want to use the string to insert it into a table in mySQL database... how can I use this value? is there a way to just say: String=namevalue;